# WordPress on Elastic Beanstalk, where store the file compare to Cpanel?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services

I just got into aws world and try to migrate wordpress to AWS by  [this](https://github.com/aws-samples/eb-php-wordpress)

using Elastic Beanstalk, Elastic Filesystem, Amazon RDS and Route 53

some concept still confused me

1. where/which services store the file?
   I was using cpanel as hosting,
   the steps were
   if anything need to be modified, just go to the file manger and make change > refresh the browser then it done the deployment.
2. how to process when using AWS?
3. in AWS where the files at? my guess is it's on eb environment and store as zip file in S3
   just curious if update a article with picture upload, where the files are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. where/which services store the file? I was using cpanel as hosting, the steps were if anything need to be modified, just go to the file manger and make change > refresh the browser then it done the deployment.

Your current version of the application will be stored in `/var/app/current`. During the deployment of a new version, `/var/app/staging` will be used for storage, and the the staging folder will **fully replace** `current`, so you will loose all files if have there. That's why, the link that you provided uses [EFS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/index.html) file system to overcome this limitation.

> 2. how to process when using AWS?

I don't understand what do you want to process.

> 3. in AWS where the files at? my guess is it's on eb environment and store as zip file in S3 just curious if update a article with picture upload, where the files are?

See point 1.